# Can't add build to test for Internal tester

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode7, testflight

I can't add processed builds for Internal testing. But it's available for external testing though. This is strange. Any ideas on this?

**Internal testing**
[image: Internal testing]

**External testing**
[image: External testing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, i changed the version of the app to 0.1 (previously it was 1.0). And uploaded a new build to the TestFlight. and it worked this time.

But, still issue with version 1.0 though.

Comment: keep version 1.0 and build 4.0 or higher than before

Comment: Tried with V1.0 build 5.0 but didn't work @MuhammadAdnan

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Higher build numbers did not change anything.

Comment: @carlossless Did you try changing the app version? not the build number.

Comment: Cool @carlossless